# Linq and Infinite Recursion through Extensions

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

Given this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4263048

Which is excellent, how can we be sure that out query won't get into an infinite recursion?

With the example class provided, if the boxes point to one another and the answer doesn't exist, would it search forever? Or is that part of the Linq "execution plan", for lack of the actual word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it returns itself at the first yield return, and only recursives if the contents of the box are not empty; so when you get an empty box the recursion unfolds.

The FindBoxBySize looks to match on size (from found items) or default.

Comment: Right, but say you have two boxes that contain each other in the Contents object, or a box that contains itself. (Doesn't make sense real-world, I know.) So it will always recurse because it never finds an empty box.

Comment: That would be the fault of the implementation, not the code; you can make any recursion fail my abusing the code in such ways.

Comment: Alright, one last time, correct me if I'm wrong here: Pretending that Box was just simply Node and we might not be looking at a tree structure, but a network (as I am), this algorithm would fail, because it relies on always finding leaves at the end. Right?

Comment: Yes the stopping criteria for the algorithm is that a box is empty. If this does not suit your implementation then you need to (a) add additional stopping criteria, (b) or(/and) change the existing stopping criteria. In recursion it is the stopping criteria that stops the recursion and then the stack unfolds. One example may be the 'depth' to recurse: 'if (depth == maxDepth) return this;