# Recursive hierarchy using linq get parent also

Tags: c#, .net, linq, recursion, hierarchy

Im trying to recursively using linq get hierarchy for given data.
For example I have object like this:

```
class Parent {
            Comment comment;
        }
```

```
class Comment {
            Guid id;
            string text;
            List<Comment> replies;
        }
```

Replies can also have replies and so on.
data for example

```
{
  "parent": {
    "comment": {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "",
      "replies": [
        {
          "comment": {
            "id": 4,
            "text": "",
            "replies": [
              {
                "comment": {
                  "id": 5,
                  "text": "",
                  "replies": [
                    {
                      "comment": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "text": "",
                        "replies": []
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "comment": {
            "id": 7,
            "text": "",
            "replies": [
              {
                "comment": {
                  "id": 8,
                  "text": "",
                  "replies": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So for given ID 5 I want to return parent object and comments with ids 3,4,5 and 6

I tried something like this
But this code returns only for childs in second level. If that ID is present in third level than it will not be returned

```
parent.replies.Where(reply =>
            reply.replies.Any(r => r.Id == ID)
        ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ and recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257117/linq-and-recursion)

Comment: No. Just tried and tested. It returns only child element with given ID

Comment: Is there a typo in your JSON? Should the id for the comment after comment 5 be id = 6?